# TOC: Avoid rule to be showed in TOC

Tags: table-of-contents, rules

How can I avoid showing the rule in the TOC:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,graphicx,blindtext}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{showframe,fontawesome}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\geometry{nomarginpar,margin = 1in}
\setlength{\headheight}{81pt}
\definecolor{MYCOLOR}{HTML}{6A6A6A}
\definecolor{mycolor}{HTML}{6A6A6A}




\pagestyle{fancy}

\newcommand{\raisedrulefill}[2][0ex]{\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill}

\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{
    \titleformat{\section}{
        \bfseries
        \scshape
        \raggedright
        \uppercase
    }{}{0em}{\llap{\faFile\thinspace\thinspace}}
    \section{#1 \color{mycolor}{\raisedrulefill[0.4ex]{1pt}}}
}

\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.65\textwidth}
        \mysection{foo}
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
        \mysection{bar}
        \blindtext
    \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the optional argument of `\section`, which is used in TOC and marks.

```
\section[#1]{#1 \color{mycolor}{\raisedrulefill[0.4ex]{1pt}}}
```

[image]